# The 13.04 installation freezes on 'choose language', what should I do?

Tags: installation, 13.04, 64-bit, asus

I am trying to install `Ubuntu 13.04 (64bit)` on a desktop with `Asus M5A88V-Evo mb`, but the installation process stucks when you choose the language and the Ubuntu Background appears. It just stay in that blue background.

I have Windows 7 64bit install, and i Installed ubuntu on other PC without problem.
Also the same problem appears and when you try to run Ubuntu without Installation.
I Tried booting with DVD and USB

Comment: Have you tried to download the Ubuntu image again, it might be a broken download.

Comment: Yes. The DVD works fine (as a liveCd) on an old Dell laptop. (I cant boot through USB with the laptop)

Comment: Then it sounds like a bug to me. Have you tried the 12.04 LTS version?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. After removing GPU (amd 6870)and USB connected items, I found that the problem was an old ATA HDD which was connected to the MB. Also after Installing Ubuntu, connecting that HDD and restart, Ubuntu was freezing again after login.

Thnx for the help